# Easiest way to add popup dialog with snippet of html/text using a wysiwyg editor?

Tags: wysiwyg

My client isn't too technical and cannot code, but she wants a popup dialog when the user clicks on a link to show a snippet of html or text.

What solutions are there for the end user to be able to add and edit text popups like this using only a wysiwyg editor without having to code in stuff?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: clicks a link on the content and it pops up like this: http://prntscr.com/cl6sbl -- but done using the editor without  having to code anything

Comment: Are you using WYSIWYG  module with CKEditor plugin, or standalone [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module?

Comment: stand alone ckeditor

Comment: Drupal version 7 or 8?

Comment: Did you get to take a look at the answers you got so far? Any updates? Problem still persists? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not know of a single module that can achieve that functionality out of the box, here is how I'd do it:

1. Create a new content-type with an  entity reference, a trigger
   string and a dialog text area.
2. In the referenced node, query for any referencing entities from the new content type. Most likely with a preprocess function and preferably in a newly created custom module.
3. Load referencing entities if found and attach a JS file that will receive the triggers and dialogue values through the settings array.
4. If all is well then JS file will have triggers in selectors and
   dialogues to display.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a recipe for that:

- [CKEditor Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link): Used for linking to other content in your Drupal. In this case, I would create another Content-Type, e.g. Popup Snippet or sth similar. This is an optional component, depending on your exact requirements.
- [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node): Used for presenting node content in a popup, stripped of the surrounding regions and other theme elements. It also provides an easy way to turn links into popups, by providing a 'magic' class, `colorbox-node`. This is the main component, and the main idea, allowing the user to 'popify' links by adding a class name to the link's properties in CKEditor.

Below are some screenshot of the result on a D7.

**Linking to content**
[image]

**Setting the colorbox-node class**
[image]

**End-result**
[image]

Good luck!